# ng-class in not evaluated

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, class

Consider this js code:

```
  // class inside controller TODO: refactor
  $scope.$watch('concat.country', function(newValue) {
    if (highRisk.indexOf(newValue) !== -1) {
      alert(newValue + " is a high risk country");
      $scope.riskClass = "highRisk";
    } else if (mediumRisk.indexOf(newValue) !== -1) {
      alert(newValue + " is a medium risk country");
      $scope.riskClass = "mediumRisk";
    } else {
      $scope.riskClass = "";
    }
  });
```

With template

```
 <div ng-class="{{riskClass}}" class="col-lg-10">
```

The logic works great. I can see in Chrome ng-class is set to correct value, but background is not changed in and element inspector doesn't show the class.

Why is ng-class not evaluated? `{{riskClass}}` is not legal/correct?

PS I know this code is far from perfect.

Comment: `ng-class="riskClass"` you dont need to wrap then in `{{`

Comment: ugh. 30 secs. Thanks a lot. Wonder how this works though https://coderwall.com/p/r3_geg

Comment: As that article you listed continues its wrapped in single {} which you can do when the class is added on a condition. Example: ng-class="{active:contition}" - that would assign the active class when the condition is met.

Comment: The very first example in the article is a misuse. The `{{active}}` will be evaluated only once, and never get re-evaluated again when the `active` has been changed. Or it might had worked in the past, angularjs sure has changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 2):

you wont need ng-class if the class name is in string...

```
<div class="col-lg-10 {{riskClass}}">
```

you should use ng-class when you have some bool condition on basis of which you want to add the class.